# What triggers MVC JSON Get blocking - intermittently working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a JSON method that accepts a GET request and returns a JSON object (not array). I'm aware of JSON Hijacking and the implications.  I've read the [Phil Haack post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).  The problem is that the method works 98% of the time for GET and POST.  The other times I'm recording this error:

```
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to 
third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set
JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
```

My method is simple and takes a single integer parameter...

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MyMediaJSON(int? id) {
    <get data & return result>
}
```

What conditions **trigger** the message?  What should look for as I debug this?

Comment: would that because you are using `ActionResult` instead of `JsonResult` and for an odd algorithm problem it get's screwed? Can you log what are you passing as well all the time? run **Fiddler** and test, once you get an error, check the differences.

Comment: @balexandre - interesting that you point it out.  Since I'm having trouble reproducing I'm going to have to roll the change in result type then watch for the intermittent error.  I suspect the request is being blocked prior to having a chance to return, but I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just looked at the MVC source code and it do not add up with what you are saying in your question.

To me it looks like `JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet` is used for all JSON results per default. Hence you should get the error message each time you try to return JSON from a controller using a GET request (without specifying `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`).

The actual control is done in `JsonResult.ExecuteResult` and looks like:

```
if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
    String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed);
}
```

> What conditions trigger the message? What should look for as I debug this?

Any actions that are getting invoked through GET that returns `JsonResult` without specifying `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. (the `Json` method in the controller uses `JsonResult`)

Comment: Thanks for digging.  I went back and dug through the MVC source and you're right.   In my case, i was seeing an intermittent problem b/c my framework was checking for session timeouts and in the case of an ajax request it returned a JSON Result.   My normal json results allowed get, but the session timeout signal was missing the flag.  Thanks again.